# WooCommerce full width product pages

Tags: css, woocommerce

I need help with my WooCommerce. What code is needed to get full page width on the product pages? I've tried but can't get it to work. I have tried to add a code in customize css.

```
.main-container {width:100%;max-width:100%}
#page, .container {width:100%}
```

Nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you use bootstrap you have to do changes on your container and your column.
Set container to full

```
body.single-product .container {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Set column to full

```
body.single-product .container .col-lg-8.col-md-12.mb-5.mb-lg-0 {
    max-width: 100%;
    flex: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Add This CSS Wordpress Customize in Additional CSS:

```
 @media (min-width: 992px){
    .single-product .col-lg-8 {
    flex: auto !important;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}
```